# Suggestions Help for server client communcation

Tags: apache-flex

I have 12 display monitors installed in different floors in a building. These monitors display announcements that will be update once in a day. i'm retrieving these announcements from db and storing in an array and displaying it all day long.

In addition to this, I have a requirment to display emergency alert messages on the monitors. My Server is a windows 2000 server. i'm using asp for creating the JSON object.

for the emergency alert im thinking of doing this

Create a page in asp  that lets user to enter emergency msg and save to db. create a page in asp that will check if there an emergency msg in db and show it in a asp page in json.
Create a timer that pings this json page every 1 second. if it's available then show it.

Is there any other sophisticated method available to poll the server or to send messages from server to client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since its only for 12 monitors I'd go with the solution you have chosen. 
Using web-sockets with something like node.js would be fun but i think its a bit overkill for this.